Why is my locally installed Python package not found when installed as an editable package?
I am using Python 3.10.7 64-bit in VSCode. I have a Python package "pxml" built using setuptools. It is in a folder with an empty __init.py__ and a pyproject.toml containing:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
[project]
name = "pxml"
version = "0.0.1"
dependencies = []

When installed normally with python -m pip install path/to/folder, an import pxml works just fine. However, when installed with python -m pip install -e path/to/folder, I get the error "Import 'pxml' cannot be resolved."
python -m pip list shows the package installed and when I run a simple test file to access one of pxml's methods it runs just fine. Making sure that I am using the same python version in the terminal, python -c "import pxml" reports no errors.
One thing that does show up as an autocomplete option when I type import pxml is __editable___pxml_0_0_1_finder, not sure if that is a clue.
The directory structure is:
 - src
     + XML
         * pxml.py
         * __init__.py 
         * pyproject.toml
     + test.py

I am using test.py to import pxml.
Any ideas?

When you say "the import cannot be resolved", what exactly do you mean? What is the exact error you are getting as I wasn't able to reproduce.

@ukBaz I edited the post for clarification.

I've been unable to reproduce the error you are getting. I was getting it initially with my test before I did the pip install .... I still got the error initially after I did the pip install ... but I closed VSCode and re-opened it; after that VSCode was able to resolve the location of the pxml module.

Note that your project depends on itself: dependencies = ["pxml"], is that on purpose? This seems unnecessary and I recommend to remove this. -- What is the directory structure of the project's source tree? I recommend you include this info in your question.

@sinoroc Both done.

The directory structure of your project's source tree is unconventional, and it is very likely the source of the issues you encounter. This structure you are showing us does not seem to be on purpose, rather a mistake (but maybe there is purpose that I do not see). -- I recommend you follow this tutorial and pay close attention to the project's source tree directory structure. And think about what do you want your top-level import package to be.

If you want to have a module that is a single file then your directory structure might confuse setuptools (although it did the correct thing for me when I tested your file structure). If you wanted to be specific about the single file then use the keyword py-modules. Slightly out of date because is uses setup.py rather than pyproject.toml, this answer might offer some insight in to how to organize your files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69446898/7721752

For the package structure shown in your question, this is import statement is incorrect:
import pxml

pxml is not a top-level import, it is a submodule of a package named XML.
If python -c "import pxml" works that is only by accident and you happen to have pxml visible on sys.path for some reason - perhaps the subdirectory XML is your current working directory, and it is resolved that way because the first element of sys.path is the empty string.
Instead, the import should be one of:
import XML.pxml

or
from XML import pxml


Ahhh... I see now. This was the clarification I needed. Thanks!
